# Clearing main terminal screen from a Python service

Tags: python, terminal, raspberry-pi

Long story short: I'm building a camera with the Raspberry Pi and Python. I'm running Raspbian Lite (Because I don't need graphics) and the camera starts up as a service. It brings up a preview of what the camera sees, which is great.

Because the preview isn't the same dimensions as the screen itself, the terminal shows at the edges.

I would like to be able to clear this screen before starting my camera preview up, so that it's not visible when the camera preview is live.

Due to the nature of the project, the user turns on the camera, and the camera system starts. There's no possibility of manual input - nor do I want there to be.

As you can imagine, there's hundreds of thousands of answers saying to use some variation of the 'clear' command. These work great.... for the terminal you're currently using. Which means the python code running as a service can't touch the main console with it.

This super basic question does make it incredibly hard to find answers, though, as every search attempt I made just flooded me with different variations of "Use 'clear'".

PyGame is out, as I am running Raspbian Lite - and using a package as large as PyGame for such a simple solution is impractical. I've tried it for a handful of other things, and it's not succeeded at those.

Comment: Maybe you can share a photo of what you are referring to?

Comment: You can probably use `dd` to blast a bunch of zeroes from `/dev/zero` to the framebuffer which will make the screen black. That would look something like `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/fb?` maybe with some improvement that works out the number of bytes needed.

Comment: Any luck with my suggestion?